# Netplan static routes break my DNS

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, netplan

On my network, `192.168.1.0/24`, I have a sub-network with a pfSense router (static "WAN" IP `192.168.1.90`, LAN and OPT interface IPs `192.168.2.{1,129}`) and two subnets therein, `192.168.2.{0,128}/25` with two machines at IPs `192.168.2.30` and `192.168.2.130`.

When I uncomment the static routes below,

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp5s0:
      nameservers:
        search: [ bjd2385.com ]
        addresses: [ 192.168.1.65, 192.168.1.70, 8.8.8.8 ]
#      routes:
#        - to: 192.168.2.0/25
#          via: 192.168.1.90/24
#          metric: 100
#        - to: 192.168.2.128/25
#          via: 192.168.1.90/24
#          metric: 100
  bridges:
    vmbr0:
      interfaces:
        - enp5s0
      addresses: [ 192.168.1.63/24 ]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
```

I can no longer resolve internal DNS (or external). My `resolv.conf` only contains the following line.

```
nameserver fe80::7ad2:94ff:fe6f:b7ce%4
```

I've also tried setting `via` on both to `192.168.2.1` and `192.168.2.129`, respectively (which I would expect to be more proper), but with that I get the same result.

```
$ ping dc
ping: dc: Name or service not known
```

While the actual address of the above DN is `192.168.1.65`, and the applicable search domain should allow the FQDN to be resolved at that address.

Thoughts on what could be breaking DNS with this configuration?

Comment: Posting as a comment as I am no expert on `netplan` configuration, but I **think** that the `routes` sections should go under your bridge `vmbr0`, as `enp5s0` has no IP address assigned.

Comment: @MrShunz I seem to get the same results both ways; I've tried that as well. If you believe I should update my query with that kind of listing instead, I would be happy to do so.

Comment: No problem. I just thought that usually there _should_ be a network active when you want to create a static route using an IP on said network.